# Is a comma always needed before 'although' – or is it just a matter of style?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions

I know it technically isn't correct, but to me it just looks awkward without it. For example (just reading through a friend's gig review):

> The videos were surprisingly hard hitting, although equally I don’t
>   think Muse will ever get to the Rage Against The Machine level of
>   political activism.

I think this could be substituted for 'but', which is why I think it works best with a comma.

However, the phrase 'even though' sounds better without one:

> It was incredibly heartwarming to witness even though I wasn’t able
>   to see him myself.

What are some opinions?

I'm bad with commas (a serial abuser of them), and I'm only really starting to learn English punctuation properly!

Comment: Please include the actual question in the body, not just the title.

Comment: It's not a cut-and-dried thing -- use comma where it makes a semantic difference, helps disambiguate, or improves readability. (Notice the comma before *or* here.)

Comment: Sorry, I will do next time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "I know it technically isn't correct"? It's the first time I hear that. Where do you know it from? Please provide an authority saying that (since you *know* rather than *guess* it, that should be trivial). Likewise, can you perhaps elaborate what "technically correct" means in the first place? That is not a term I am familiar with. Lastly, commas are punctuation, not grammar. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't understand the quotation, but I am assuming that "Muse" has some connection with the "hard-hitting" videos.

Personally, I **would** have put a comma before *although*: it gives a break in reading; and the part before *although* could be a stand-alone sentence, and makes sense without the extra clause.

Yes, you could probably use *but* or *even though* instead of *although* - but I don't think that should change the punctuation: all of them should be preceded by a comma for the reasons given about. Changing the actual words used, while still retaining the same meaning, should **not** (normally) result in a change of punctuation.

Commas serve many purposes. In this particular case (without going into detailed grammatical reasons), they aid the reader in several ways:

- knowing when they can pause in reading the sentence;
- in indicating that the writer is about to introduce an *additional* 'thought' and preparing the reader for that;
- in indicating that the following clause is not essential to the first clause.

Answer (score -2):

The question is not clear!

But I think that it's not correct to write "but" without a comma. Because this is what the rules said first, and also the comma is considered as a point of relaxation for the reader to take a breath. So it's very important to add a comma before *but*.

Comment: I am sure this is well intentioned, but you really need to take more care with your posts. This is a site about the subtleties of the Emglish language (which are many and deceptive); txt spk is both unhelpful and disrespectful.

Comment: yes i know that ... and i am sorry if i wrote some thing that make you nerv!! soory!!